# VSTS build error: non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: azure-devops, build-definition, azure-pipelines

VSTS Build definition is failing and I can't make heads or tails of this error...

`C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Detected NuGet version 3.3.0.212 / 3.3.0
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.`

[Nuget Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0YUd.png) build step, [Visual Studio Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu2lR.png) build step

Are the build steps out of order? Am I not referencing the right file on the Nuget Installer step? The Nuget Installer calls for a nuget.config xml file but my .Net Core app houses its dependencies in a project.json file. Please let me know if I need to provide more information, or what's missing from the post that would make this easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .Net Core app, using [dotnet-restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore) command to restore package. The dotnet restore command uses NuGet to restore dependencies as well as project-specific tools that are specified in the project.json file.

Add Command Line step to your build definition. (Tool: dotnet, Argument: restore, Working folder: [folder path, which contains the project.json file])

[image]

[There](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure) is an article that can help you.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: More fun. So that was a test project I created in order to play with build definitions. What tool do I need to use in order to build a dnx451 (or dnxcore50) app?

Comment: @SoloSheff For new question, it's better to create a new thread.