# VSTS Build - NUGET restore error: Non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I am new to VSTS.
I want to build my solution. For some reason the Visual Studio template that was once there is no longer. So I use the ASP.Net template.
Currently it is failing on the Nuget Restore;
[image]

This is set as follows;
[image]

When I go to the advanced restore options and choose V4 instead of the default V3.3, I get this error instead;

```
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet Installer
Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
Version      : 0.2.31
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================

C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Detected NuGet version 4.0.0.2283 / 4.0.0
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true

d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive d:\a\1\s\SIR.sln -ConfigFile d:\a\1\s\SIR.sln
NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path: 'd:\a\1\s\SIR.sln'.
  Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.

Error: d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1

Packages failed to install

******************************************************************************

Finishing: NuGet restore

******************************************************************************
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What kind of project are you building? classic asp.net, asp.net core, ..?

Comment: There already is a similar question, please check if the solution also fixes your problems (this is .net core specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383096/vsts-build-error-non-whitespace-before-first-tag

Comment: The solution contains projects one of which is core and the others are not. I do not understand the solution to the question you posted. Where do I use the dotnet-restore commsnd?

Comment: Are you using VS 2017? if so, make sure you are using the hosted vs 2017 queue for the build definition

Comment: Yes it is VS 2017 and I have selected Hosted for the Default agent queue.

Comment: You need to use Hosted VS 2017 agent instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS build error: non-whitespace before first tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383096/vsts-build-error-non-whitespace-before-first-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it is a VS 2017 project, try to use Hosted VS 2017 agent instead.

Update:

Sepecify Nuget 4.0 version of Nuget restore step/task:

[image]

EDIT - From the comments below, the problem was fixed by making blank the "Path to nugget.config" parameter

Comment: @arame3333 There are Hosted and Hosted VS 2017 agents, you need to use Hosted VS 2017 agent.

Comment: Ok you were right that I missed that. So I set the agent to "Hosted VS 2017 agent". Done the build again and I get the same error.

Comment: @arame3333 You said that you use the ASP.Net template, how do you create project with that template? Can you share a simple sample on the OneDrive?

Comment: I do not have access to OneDrive here. To be more accurate I think it was the ASP.NET Core (.Net Framework) template. The solution contains 1 .Net Core project and some other ASP.NET projects that are not Core. Is there an image from the build I can post here that would be helpful?

Comment: The answer of the question I linked in the comments still applies. The "nuget restore" tasks only supports NuGet 3.3 and 3.5 but you need at least NuGet 4. use `dotnet restore` instead.

Comment: So, hiding under the Advanced tab. Why was the default set to 3.3? Anyway I run it again and I got a new error message; Error: d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1

Packages failed to install

Comment: @arame3333 This is the task action. Try to change system.debug variable value to true and queue build, then post the detail errors here.

Comment: It looks like I made a silly mistake. The path to the Nuget.Config file should actually have a Nuget.Config file. Although I am wondering where to locate it. Anyway this is the error message: "[command]d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive d:\a\1\s\SIR.sln -ConfigFile d:\a\1\s\SIR.sln
2017-05-22T09:45:27.0971545Z NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path: 'd:\a\1\s\SIR.sln'.
2017-05-22T09:45:27.0971545Z   Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1."

Comment: I just removed SIR.sln from the "path to the Nuget.Config file" and not replaced it, and Nuget is restoring anyway. I have a new error but that is something else I will look at.

Comment: @arame3333 You don't need to specify NuGet.config, leave it blank. If you need to restore the packages that in the private feed, you can specify NuGet.config file with necessary source(s) and credential. (the default nuget.config file is in C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet folder.)

Comment: Yes that fixed it and answered the question. Although I am now getting a return code: 1 Packages failed to install error message and even though the debug variable is still set to true and I can't find where this problem is.